# Rails 3.0.0.beta Install problem: can't find executable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install the rails 3.0.0.beta and I'm running into this issue:

```
justins-mac-: justinz$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
justins-mac-justinz$ rails -help
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:384:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.0.0.beta (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/bin/rails:19
justins-mac-justinz$ rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:384:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.0.0.beta (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/bin/rails:19
justins-mac-justinz$
```

Any clues as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After upgrading rubygems and cleaning up you need to:

```
gem install railties --pre
```

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo gem install railties --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Since that does nothing, try

```
sudo gem cleanup
```

then reinstall.